# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'head' my compiler is giving error at line 51

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to learn linked list in ppython. This is a really simple code. All I am trying to do here is to call a class's constructor. But it is giving me an error. It is saying:

```
#This is the code I have written please help me resolve this problem
class node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None
class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self,head):
        self.head=None
    def insertathead(self,data):
        newnode=node(data)
        if(self.head==None):
            self.head=newnode
        else:
            newnode.next=self.head
            self.head=newnode
    def insertatend(self,data):
        newnode=node(data)
        if(self.head==None):
            self.head=newnode
        else:
            temp=self.head
            while(temp.next!=None):
                temp=temp.next
            temp.next=newnode
    def insert(self,position,data):
        newnode=node(data)
        count=1
        if(self.head==None):
            self.head=newnode
        elif(position==1):
            newnode.next=self.head
            self.head=newnode 
        else:
            while(temp.next!=None):
                if(count==position):
                    break
                else:
                    prev=temp
                    temp=temp.next
                    count=count+1
        prev.next=newnode
        newnode.next=temp
    def printlist(self):
        if(self.head==None):
            print("your list is empty")
        else:
            temp=self.head
            while(temp.next!=None):
                print(temp,end=' ')
                temp=temp.next               

mylist=linkedlist()
mylist.insertathead(25)
mylist.printlist
```

```
File "D:\roug1.py", line 51, in <module>
    mylist=linkedlist()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'head'
```

this is the error my compiler is giving .I don't what to do. Can anyone provide me with the correct code

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're calling linkedlist constructor with no arguments:

```
 mylist=linkedlist()
```

whereas in the class definition it has one positional arguments 'head':

```
class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self, head):
```

To fix the error you'd need to provide 'head' argument to the constructor, e.g.

```
mylist=linkedlist(node('Head'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a node for the head of the LinkedList class so that it knows what to reference: linkedlist(Node)

Your __ init __(self, head) method for LinkedList requires the head parameter which I'm assuming is a node.  So, when you instantiate the object you need to give it a reference to what you want to make as the "head" node

ex.

```
head_node = Node(25)
mylist=linkedlist(head_node)

# now do whatever you want
mylist.insertathead(25)
mylist.printlist()
```